# Bulk Insert in Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, orm, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I received post data as string as follow:

```
data01,data02
data11,
data21,data22
...
dataxx,dataxx
```

The data can be as long as 10.000 rows, column 1 is mandatory and unique, column 2 is optional.

so have sanitize the string (ensure column 1 unique (only within the input data - not through DB), format, etc.) and have convert it to array:

```
[0:
    [col1: data01,
     col2: data02],
 1:
    [col1: data11,
     col2: ""],
 2:
    [col1: val11,
     col2: val12],
 .....
 9999:
    [col1: dataxx,
     col2: dataxx],
]
```

so that array now sits at my Controller...

now, on my own opinion, it's best to send that array to mysql through Stored Proc and let SP do the bulk insert job (let me know if you have a better way, and why)

questions:

1. how to pass that array to Mysql?
2. and should I use insert select on duplicate key ignore?
3. I need to get a report to be presented in view, to tell user which data column 1 is duplicated (ignored)

And just a side question,
if i do:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'array.*.column1' => 'unique:items'
]);
```

will it actually query to DB as many as my data quantity? (eg. 10000 times?)
I just affraid the code performance is too expensive

Answer (score 0):

What my solution for this is

1. First define rules of validation it always run on request not on DB.

--

```
$rules = array("column 1"  => "unique:KEY_NAME|required");
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
```

2. Make an array

--

```
$data = array(
array('k1'=> 'v1', 'k2'=> 'v2'), all data

);
```

3. Now use `Eloquent::insert();` and pass data into this.

Well don't query on database. Just take array difference on final data and request data. Also add one more column which state whether is duplicate or not. So it's gonna save a good time.